# Может ли быть полностью рациональным простой рефлексный агент данной среды?

Tags: искусственный-интеллект

[image: Среда пылесоса]

Имеется модифицированная версия среды пылесоса из изображения, в которой агенту назначается штраф в один пункт за каждое движение. Может ли быть полностью рациональным простой рефлексный агент для этой среды?